# compiling SFML with cmake and mingw under windows

Tags: windows, cmake, mingw, sfml

When i try to run cmake to build a project where i include the SFML library i get the following Error: `SFML found but version too low (requested: 2.4, found: 1.x.x)`

I downloaded only the source of the newest Version of the library (SFML-2.4.2). I than run cmake (with MinGW Makefiles) And build the binaries into the same folder.
I copied the FindSFML into an subfolder of my project. 
After that i had the following folder structure

```
SFML-2.4.2\
  cmake\
    Modules\
       FindSFML.cmake
  CMakeFiles
  doc
  ...
  include
  lib
  src
  ..

sfml-games\
  tetris\
    cmake_modules\
      FindSFML.cmake
    CMakeLists.txt
    main.cpp
  tetris-build
    ...
```

My CMakeLists.txt contains the following stuff:

```
project(Tetris)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8) 
aux_source_directory(. SRC_LIST)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake_modules")
Find_package(SFML 2 REQUIRED system window graphics network audio)

include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_LIST}) 

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SFML_LIBRARY})
```

I found that in cmake the entry CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX (which i dont get) is set to `C:\Program Files (x86)\SFML` so i put the library and the lib of SFML into C:\Program Files (x86)\SFML. (what is that CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX and should i realy always copy the library and lib folders into my `C:\Program Files (x86)\` ??). Now my cmake runs through but when i try to compile the code i get a lot of undifined references to '_imp__....'

By the way on linux i just installed SFML via `sudo apt-get install libsfml-dev` and it works out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing things. `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` is the default location where to put SFML when you build the `install` target (i.e. running `make install`). This has nothing to do with your other issues.

You don't have to install SFML (or any other library) somewhere under `C:\Program Files`. That's completely up to you.

What I found to be rather neat is installing MinGW to `C:\usr` (or creating a symlink to your installation folder) and also use that path for `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` when building SFML.

This way MinGW should behave pretty much the way you're used to from Linux (i.e. not having to specify paths for include dir or libraries etc.).

As for your undefined reference errors, you should create a new question only asking for these (and then include at least a few of them), as they have nothing to do with the installation directory.

Right now I can only guess, but it's most likely due to you using the wrong CMake variables for the linker. You won't notice this on Linux, since SFML will be in the default search path (which will also happen if you use `C:\usr` as described above).

To try fixing this, use this line:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SFML_LIBRARIES} ${SFML_DEPENDENCIES})
```